# Android Intent Butchers Data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceScreen I'm working on and I've added a Preference which acts as a clickable link.

I have the following code:

```
<Preference android:title="@null" android:height="10px" android:paddingTop="0px" android:summary="Learn More" android:key="mypref">
    <intent 
        android:action="android.intent.action.View"
        android:mimeType="text/html"
        android:data="http://www.google.com"/>
</Preference>
```

When I click this preference,

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.View dat=http: typ=text/html }

I've tried escaping characters, but the behavior is even worse (only "www.google.com" gives an empty dat).

Comment: put View in uppercase, android.intent.action.VIEW and remove mimeType

Comment: @spezzino You are both a gentleman and a scholar. This did the trick. Feel free to make it an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to call action.VIEW (notice uppercase word)

Also, remove mimeType

```
<Preference android:title="@null" android:height="10px" android:paddingTop="0px" android:summary="Learn More" android:key="mypref">
<intent 
    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:data="http://www.google.com"/>
</Preference>
```